# How do I convert a database number to hex when the field might be null?

Tags: c#, linq, hex

I have trouble to convert from decimal to hex.

Here is my code:

```
select new
{
    MessageID = table1.Field<Int32?>("MessageID"),
    MessageIDHex = (String)table1.Field<Int32>("MessageID").ToString("X")
}
```

It gives me Error

> with DBNUll.Value cant not change to System.In32

So I have tried

```
MessageIDHex= (String)table1.Field<Int32?>("MessageID").ToString("X")}
```

but it gives me another error.

How can I fix it or it does have another way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `MessageID` can be DBNull. The simplest solution is to read the value as a *nullable* int (to prevent the conversion error from occurring). If you use `Field` with a nullable type, `DBNull` is automatically converted to `null`, which can then be coerced to 0 with the `??` operator:

```
MessageIDHex = (table1.Field<Int32?>("MessageID") ?? 0).ToString("X")
```

Alternatively, if you prefer, you can have DBNull values in the database result in an empty or a null string for `MessageIDHex`:

```
MessageIDHex = table1.IsNull("MessageID") ? "" : table1.Field<Int32>("MessageID").ToString("X")
MessageIDHex = table1.IsNull("MessageID") ? null : table1.Field<Int32>("MessageID").ToString("X")
```

Comment: MaxHex = table1.IsNull("Maximum") ? null : (table1.Field<String>("Maximum")).ToString("X")                                          How to convert string to hex?

Comment: "String to hex" does not make sense. How would you convert "Hello World" to hex?

Comment: I meant string is a double like 100,01 so i should parse or convert to Doube and then to Hex

Comment: The first part is easy, you just answered it yourself: Parse to Double (using [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx)). Your second part is more tricky: Are you sure that you need to convert a *floating-point number* (e.g. 12.3) to hex?

Comment: so i did MaxHex = table1.IsNull("Maximum") ? null : Double.Parse(table1.Field<string>("Maximum")).ToString("X"), but i got Formatexception

Comment: Double does not support ToString("X"). Let me ask you again: Do you really need to convert a *floating-point number* to hex (Example: Decimal `0.75` = Hex `0.C`) ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, please start a new question for that.